# Should rel=canonical be used for various images in a gallery?

Tags: seo, images, rel-canonical, photo-gallery

I have made a portfolio website for my wife. She is an illustrator. Website contains one page with four sections - gallery, about, testimonials and a contact form.

The gallery navigation is made in Javascript but with a normal HREF attribute pointing to the full version of the website with chosen image (in case of Javascript disabled). So basically a root url has same content as other image "subpages" except image itself. So every image has its own subpage with same sections like on the main page (about contact form etc.).

Should I add rel canonical for subpages other than main page?

Comment: So your site structure is something like this `example.com/1/1.png` and `example.com/2/2.png` and your 1 and 2 directory have same contents, right? and that content is also same to main homepage? and do you link your image directory(1 and 2) from anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If your Image page URL is varied in different device sizes like www.example.com/image-page in desktop and www.example.com/m/image-page in mobile; in that case you have to set canonical URL for image pages.

But if your URL's are same for all devices and responsive then no need to define it.